# Calculation of time a record spent in particular status

Tags: mysql, sql

Could anybody please help me with the next task? Here is a problem:
we have a table of history(status changes of records) and we need to calculate how much time (in days) a record was in a particular status. Here is the structure of history table:

```
ID| RecordId| CreatedDate         | Field  | OldValue      | NewValue
1 | Record1 | 2013-08-07 09:40:31 | Status | Open          | Awaiting Info
2 | Record1 | 2013-08-08 07:30:20 | Status | Awaiting Info | Open
3 | Record1 | 2013-08-14 01:45:42 | Status | Open          | Resolved
```

As a result we need to create table like:

```
Status   | TimeSpentInStatusInDays
Open     |     2
Awaiting |     3
Resolved |     1
```

Values are for example (they are not connected to actual data set) but the structure is exactly the same and there are four different statuses we need to track.

Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Are you working directly with MySql, or do you use a language like PHP?

Comment: We use MySQL directly, thanks for an answer. I'll try that.

Comment: How is Awaiting 3 days?

Comment: @user1502952 I said previously: "Values are for example (they are not connected to actual data set)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the next date and then take the difference.  MySQL does not have the `lead()` function, you can use a correlated subquery.  The result is something like:

```
select h.status,
       sum(datediff(nextCreatedDate, CreatedDate)) as TotalDays
from (select h.*,
             (select h2.CreatedDate
              from history h2
              where h2.CreatedDate > h.CreatedDate and
                    h2.RecordID = h.RecordId
              order by h2.CreatedDate
              limit 1
             ) as nextCreatedDate
      from history h
     ) h
group by h.status;
```

This will also have decent performance with an index on `history(RecordId, CreatedDate)`.

EDIT:

The other way you can do this is with variables:

```
select h.status,
       sum(datediff(nextCreatedDate, CreatedDate)) as TotalDays
from (select h.*, @nextDate as nextCreatedDate,
             @nextdate := if(@RecordId = @nextRecordId, CreatedDate, NULL),
             @nextRecordId := RecordId,
      from history h cross join
           (select @nextdate := NULL, @nextRecordId := NULL) const
      order by RecordId, CreatedDate desc
     ) h
group by h.status;
```

I do not really like this approach, because it depends on the order of valuation of the arguments with variables in the subquery.  MySQL does not guarantee the ordering.

Comment: I've tried this one but it seems like query takes forever to execute. I've waited like for half an hour and it still didn't end. Are there any ideas how it can be optimized? I've added indexes on RecordId and CreatedDate as you suggested. We have over million records in history table and it keeps on growing. Your solution is what we need but I was able to test it only for a particular RecordId as far as it hangs when I try to go through all more than million records.

Comment: @Andrew . . . Did you add two indexes or one index?  I specifically said a composite index on `history(RecordId, CreatedDate)`.

Comment: Gordon, thanks a lot for your answers, I came up to composite index by myself, should have done it straight away...I used your first solution and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datediff function. It returns the difference in days. Say you have to calculate the number of days for record id 1 when it was in open state the query would be:

```
select DateDiff((select Created_Date from histtable where RecordId='1' and   
Status='Awaiting'), (select Created_Date from histtable where RecordId='1' and 
Status='Open'));
```

Awaiting is the next status immediately after Open status, so subtracting it from Open status date would calculate the number of days a record was in Open state.

Similarly you can get the number of days for different states of particular record, if you are using some sort of formula.

Number of days a record took to get resolved is = (Date when it got resolved - Date when it was opened), if i understand your question clearly.